# Manual sorting of dimensions in Tableau CRM

Tags: einstein-analytics, tableau-crm, tableau

I have two text field where values are numeric- 1,2,3...500. When creating a heat map, it's not sorted as field is dimensions. And they are not sorted in correct order.

Is there any way to sort the field and have it in correct order?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to convert from dimension to a measure.

You can either do it via the [data recipe](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.bi_integrate_data_prep_recipe_convert_dim_to_measure.htm&type=5) or in the dataflow itself using the transformation like dim2mea transformation.